# Pygame. Rect moves in one direction forever?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I included this :

```
    if spirect.top > mcrect.top:
        spirect.move_ip(-3,0)
    if spirect.top < mcrect.top:
        spirect.move_ip(3,0)
    if spirect.left > mcrect.left:
        spirect.move_ip(0,-3)
    if spirect.left < mcrect.left:
        spirect.move_ip(0,3)
```

in my main loop to make the spider in my game move towards the main character. After trying this, the spider(spirect) just keeps moving in one direction no matter what. How do I fix this?
All code for relevance:

```
import pygame
import sys
import time
import math





#Initializing stuff and setting display settings
wait = time.sleep
'''
print("What is your preferred screen width and height?(800,600 or greater.)")
wait(1)
print("If your chosen resolution is below 800,600 , you will be automatically set to 800,600")
wait(1)


preferred_screen_width = raw_input("Width?")
print("Dank MLG processing...")
wait(1.5)
preferred_screen_height = raw_input("Height?")
print("More dank MLG processing...")
wait(1.5)'''
#TEMP
preferred_screen_width = 800
preferred_screen_height = 600

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096)
from pygame.locals import *




'''Concepting







'''




sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('untitled.ogg')
sound.play(-1)

if int(preferred_screen_width) < 800:
    print("Illegal choice. Setting to 800,600")
    preferred_screen_width = 800
    preferred_screen_height = 600
elif int(preferred_screen_height) < 600:
    print("Illegal choice. Setting to 800,600")
    preferred_screen_width = 800
    preferred_screen_height = 600
else:
    print("Starting game")



#Ingame

pygame.display.set_caption("Spider Avoiderer")
spider_small = pygame.image.load("sag.png")

mc = pygame.image.load("mc.png")

mcrect = mc.get_rect(top = 20,left = 20)

spirect = spider_small.get_rect(top = 20,left = 20)

really_red = 255,0,0
dark_red = 171,0,0
deep_blue = 0,0,141
really_blue = 0,0,255
aa = raw_input("Would you like to use a custom background?(yes or no)")
if aa.lower() == "yes":
    print("Choose one of these colors(type exactly as written)")
    aaa = raw_input("really red, dark red, deep blue, really blue, or custom RGB")
    if aaa.lower() == "really red":
        penis = really_red
    elif aaa.lower() == "dark red":
        penis = dark_red
    elif aaa.lower() == "deep blue":
        penis = deep_blue
    elif aaa.lower() == "really blue":
        penis = really_blue
    elif aaa.lower() == "custom rgb":
        print("Enter your RGB coloring:")
        rgb_red = raw_input("Value of red? ")
        rgb_green = raw_input("Value of green? ")
        rgb_blue = raw_input("Value of blue?")
        penis = int(rgb_red),int(rgb_green),int(rgb_blue)
elif aa.lower() == "no":
    penis = 100,210,25
else:
    penis = 100,210,25


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((int(preferred_screen_width),int(preferred_screen_height)))
#fps
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
clock.tick(30)


background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background = background.convert()
background.fill((penis))




#Main loop
while True:
    screen.blit(background,(0,0))
    screen.blit(spider_small,(spirect))
    screen.blit(mc,(mcrect))








    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()


    if  pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_LEFT]:
        mcrect.move_ip(-3,0)
    elif  pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_RIGHT]:
        mcrect.move_ip(3,0)

    elif  pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP]:
        mcrect.move_ip(0,-3)

    elif  pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_DOWN]:
        mcrect.move_ip(0,3)


    if spirect.top > mcrect.top:
        spirect.move_ip(3,0)
    if spirect.top < mcrect.top:
        spirect.move_ip(-3,0)
    if spirect.left > mcrect.left:
        spirect.move_ip(0,3)
    if spirect.left < mcrect.left:
        spirect.move_ip(0,-3)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: print variables and you can see if they are correct.

Comment: btw: `preferred_screen_width` is integer - you don't have to use `int()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compare `top` (`y` coordinate) of spider and mc but then you change `x` coordinate :) So spider moves in wrong direction and it can't stop because its `top` still is different then `mc` top :)

```
if spirect.top > mcrect.top:
    spirect.move_ip(0,-3) # before: (3,0)
elif spirect.top < mcrect.top:
    spirect.move_ip(0,3) # before: (-3,0)


if spirect.left > mcrect.left:
    spirect.move_ip(-3,0) # before: (0, 3)
elif spirect.left < mcrect.left:
    spirect.move_ip(3,0) # before: (0,-3)
```

But now `spider` moves as fast as `mc` so they are in the same place all the time. Make `mc` faster or put `spider` far away of `mc`

```
mc_speed = 6 # before: 3

if  pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_LEFT]:
    mcrect.move_ip(-mc_speed,0)
elif  pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_RIGHT]:
    mcrect.move_ip(mc_speed,0)


# use `if` instead of `elif`
if  pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP]:
    mcrect.move_ip(0,-mc_speed)
elif  pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_DOWN]:
    mcrect.move_ip(0,mc_speed)
```